# Is there any subtle difference between 'mean' and 'average' in R?

Tags: r

Is there any difference between what these two lines of code do:

```
mv_avg[i-2] <- (sum(file1$rtn[i-2]:file1$rtn[i+2])/5)
```

and

```
mv_avg[i-2] <- mean(file1$rtn[i-2]:file1$rtn[i+2])
```

I'm trying to calculate the moving average of first 5 elements in my dataset. I was running a for loop and the two lines are giving different outputs. Sorry for not providing the data and the rest of the code for you guys to execute and see (can't do that, some issues).

I just want to know if they both do the same thing or if there's a subtle difference between them both.

Comment: In your case, it will give the same results. There might be a difference if you have missing values, as described [here](https://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdo/embedded/1.6.4/cdo.html#x1-320001.7.1).

Comment: You might want to look at `rollapply` and `rollmean` in the zoo package.  A number of arguments are available to fine tune how its done.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an issue with `mean` or `sum`. The example below illustrates what's happening with your code:

```
x = seq(0.5,5,0.5)
i = 8

# Your code
x[i-2]:x[i+2]
[1] 3 4 5

# Index this way to get the five values for the moving average
x[(i-2):(i+2)]
[1] 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0
```

`x[i-2]`=3 and `x[i+2]`=5, so `x[i-2]:x[i+2]` is equivalent to `3:5`. You're seeing different results with `mean` and `sum` because your code is not returning 5 values. Therefore dividing the sum by 5 does not give you the average. In my example, `sum(c(3,4,5))/5 != mean(c(3,4,5))`.

@G.Grothendieck mentioned `rollmean`. Here's an example:

```
library(zoo)

rollmean(x, k=5, align="center")

[1] 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1 6.1 7.1 8.1
```